# Generic and the Factory Pattern

Tags: java

Let's say I have an abstract class, `Element`, and an interface `Model`.

`Element` has a method `setModel(Model model)`.

Say `Element` instances reference a single `Model` implementation instance commonly, for things like deserializing from ReST, serializing to SQL tuples, etc.

Every `Element` subclass is associate with one specific `Model`, but any `Model` might be associated with any number of `Element` classes, so something like this:

```
public abstract class Element<M extends Model> {
  private M mModel;
  public void setModel(M model) {
    mModel = model;
  }
}
```

And

```
public interface Model {
  // .. stuff
}
```

Now let's say I want to create a factory that produces Elements from Models. Given that a Model might be connected to a number of Element classes, we can expect that we need to provide the specific class. So something like this in the end result:

```
ElementSubclass e = new ElementFactory(ElementSubclass.class).from(someModelInstance);
```

or....

```
ElementFactory factory = new ElementFactory(ElementSubclass.class);
for(Model model : listOfModels) {
  ElementSubClass element = factory.from(model);
  listOfElementSubClassInstances.add(element);
}
```

Getting there has been less straightforward than I'd have thought. I've ended up with something like:

```
public class ElementFactory {

  private Class<? extends Element> mElementClass;

  public <E extends Element> ContentModelElementFactory(Class<E> elementClass) {
    mElementClass = elementClass;
  }

  public <E extends Element> E from(Model model) {
    try {
      Element e = mElementClass.newInstance();
      e.setModel(model);
      return (E) e;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      //
    } 
    return null;
  }

}
```

Seems a little shaky, and lint complains about both the call to `setModel` and the cast on the line beneath.

I'd considered something like `new ElementFactory<ElementSubclass>(ElementSubclass.class)` but that reads poorly - we already designated element subclass once, it seems heavy-handed to do so as both a type and an argument.

There's also the static version, like `public static <E extends Element> E create(Class<E> clazz, Model model)` but obviously it's not a reusable as a true factory and seems a little less graceful.

Is there a better way to express this idea?

Comment: What is the objective of this ? You are trying to create the instance and setModel generically ? Am I missing something ? Also, it would be good if you add a simple example (like Employee, etc.) explaining the end goal..

Comment: @javaguy the basic purpose is to turn a model into element, by class reference.  e.g., a database query or rest call returns a model, so a factory would be a simple method to create an element of an arbitrary subclass from that model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since generic types are erased, you have to pass your `ElementSubclass` to the factory, no way around that.

If you're irritated by `new ElementFactory<ElementSubclass>(ElementSubclass.class)` then write a generic static method like `public static <E extends Element> ElementFactory<E> of(Class<E> elementClass)`. This will give you code like:

```
ElementFactory<ElementSubclass> factory = ElementFactory.of(ElementSubclass.class);
```

Which feels somewhat better.

Comment: yeah that's where i ended up as well, or pretty close (the static method referenced in the second to last paragraph).  thanks for confirming.